# Поиск в последовательности из 0 и 1

Tags: алгоритм

Дана последовательность из 0 и 1. Известно, что последний элемент не равен первому. Необходимо найти такой элемент, который не равен предыдущему за `O(logn)`.

Мне ничего хитрее, чем делать цикл, в голову не приходит. Но это `O(n/2)`.

```cpp
for(int i = 1; i < size; i = i + 2)
    if(arr[i] != arr[i-1])
        return i
```

Comment: Как твой цикл отнесётся к [1,1,0,0]? по-моему, он вообще ничего не найдёт...

Comment: А логарифмическое время ни на какие мысли не наводит?

Comment: @Akina понятно, что если бы я реализовывал то, что привел в пример, то учел бы разные частные случаи. Только я же понимаю, что мне этот вариант не подходит.

Comment: При оценке сложности константа не учитывается. Здесь линейная зависимость. И в вашем примере есть ошибка, попробуйте `0011`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ну, поскольку известно, что первый не равен последнему...
Без потери общности пусть первый - 0, последний - 1.

Делим последовательность пополам. Если посредине 0 - повторяем то же с правой частью, если 1 - с левой. И так далее, пока очередная часть не сойдется до нужной пары :)

Все. За O(log N) нужный элемент будет найден...

Comment: Интересно, а возможно ли найти за тот же логарифм не любой подходящий элемент, а строго первый?

Comment: @Yaant Не думаю. От противного - как бы вы не перебирали, я всегда могу воткнуть такой элемент на последнюю проверку :)

Comment: Ага, у меня тоже было подозрение, что невозможно, но затруднялся обосновать. :)

Comment: @Yaant Достаточно рассмотреть вариант, когда после первого половинного деления требуется работать дальше со второй половиной... уже очевидно, что для ТАКОЙ задачи показанный алгоритм неприменим.

Comment: @Akina Вопрос у меня возник не про конкретно этот алгоритм, а хоть про какой-нибудь, лишь бы с логарифмической сложностью. :)

Comment: @Yaant если это как подзадача какого-нибудь алгоритма или действие, которое нужно повторять много раз, можно построить массив префиксных сумм или дерево отрезков по данной последовательности, а затем бинарным поиском найти первый индекс i, для которого sum(0..i) > 0.

Comment: @Philippe И какова цена построения дерева? тогда уж проще один раз перебором найти нужный элемент и возвращать его за O(1)...